# Karma, Browserify on React is failing on LESS

Tags: less, karma-runner, reactjs, browserify

I'm learning how to use React, and in turn use Karma as the test runner. I'm running Karma with browserify / reactify (mocha+kai). Whenever I run `npm test`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [framework.browserify]: bundle error
ERROR [framework.browserify]: 
/Users/user/Projects/example-d3-react/src/d3Chart.less:1
.d3 {
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Not a string or buffer]
```

This happens on all LESS files in the project. I have tried adding a LESS preprocessor to the `karma.conf` like so:

```
preprocessors: {
    'src/*.less': ['less'],
    'tests/**/*.js': ['browserify']
},

browserify: {
    debug: true,
    transform: [ 'reactify' ]
},
lessPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        paths: ['src'],
        save: true,
        rootpath: './'
      },
      additionalData: {
        modifyVars: {
          'bodyColor': 'grey',
          'secondBoxColor': 'blue'
        },
        globalVars: {
          'globalBoxColor': 'red'
        }
      },
      transformPath: function(path) {
        console.log("transforming");
        return path.replace(/\.less$/, '.compiled.css');
      }
    },
```

Comment: should `'src/*.less': ['less'],` possible be  `'src/*.less': [lessPreprocessor'],`

Comment: @BassJobsen just tried it to no avail, the karma preprocessor is referenced as less afaik. Is there any way to make browserify ignore the `require('d3.less')` programatically inside the code, like a JSHint comment that sets it to ignore?

Comment: Do you have `plugins: ['karma-less-preprocessor']` defined somewhere in the conf?

Comment: @Eelke I didn't have `plugins:` defined, it was pulling in them automatically. adding 'plugins: ['karma-less-preprocessor']' requires me too add all the plugins now that were loaded automatically before (i.e `karma-browserify`) but your fix does work. Add as an answer to get the bounty :)

Comment: i expect that you that your *.less are compilled by a other preprocessor by accident. The Less compiler throws a different error, like `ERROR [preprocessor:less]: Error:Error: missing closing }`. Which command is run by `npm test` (see your Gulpfile.js), possible something like `node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js`, make sure karma used the right `karma.conf.js` file

Answer (score 1):

Add the preprocessor explicitly to the config: `plugins: ['karma-less-preprocessor']`

Comment: When you don't load `karma-less-propressor` karma should return: `WARN [preprocess]: Can not load "less", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?`

Comment: This issue wasn't rectified As @BassJobsen says, it'll warn if it's not included, which it doesn't. I can only get around it by removing the LESS

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggested answers helped me, but in case anyone is experiencing this problem, the solution that worked for me is just adding the project-specific less transform to the `package.json` file. E.g:

```
{
...
  "browserify": {
    "exclude": "*.spec.js",
    "transform": [
      "node-lessify",
      "browserify-ng-html2js"
    ]
  },
...
}
```

Build broke when doing this, since I was using the cmd line transform when building application through NPM. Removed the cmd line transform part since the `package.json` transform will apply the transform [programmatically](https://github.com/wilson428/node-lessify/issues/11), and now it works again.